# Share post on facebook, strange error

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-share

I need to implement a facebook share button on a website I am currently developing. The theory is simple and works with a simple link, e.g. https://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Freddit.com%2Fr%2Fall%2F. This works for me for random pages and my home page.

However, this does not work for all pages of that web site except the home page (/).

Example:

- Page http://www.youmatch.global/approach/
- Share link https://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youmatch.global%2Fapproach%2F

The sharing dialog states "Object not found". I am already trying for two days but I have no clue what might be the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Look at [Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youmatch.global%2Fapproach%2F)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take look at this page to see what's wrong in your sharer : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/

Comment: Perfect, thank you! That led me to the answer. I am using Wordpress and it seemed to be a Facebook caching error, even after several refreshs on the developer page. I still don't understand the workings of that error but I took the solution from https://gist.github.com/leandersikma/1c5507d2cbd29e580e94